# Displaying input 'buttons' inline with left-aligned span while floating on the right

Tags: html, css, asp.net, forms

I have a div set up as follows. I would like everything to be displayed in line, but I also want the buttons to be on the rightmost side of the div. As it stands, the buttons appear as if they are in a block below the span. I have tried setting the button's display to "inline" and "inline-block", but neither of those seem to work. How can I accomplish this?

```
<div>   
  <span>blah</span>
  <input type="submit" name="button2" value="button2" class="floatRight" />
  <input type="submit" name="button1" value="button1" class="floatRight" />
</div>
```

The class "floatRight" is :

```
.floatRight { float: right }
```

I am running IE 11

Answer (score 0):

spans and inputs are inlined naturally, but you'll want to float the buttons right to have the desired appearance you are looking for I believe:

http://jsfiddle.net/inkedraskal/odjz1suz/

```
.floatRight {float:right}
```

see fiddle

Comment: I thought it would be implied that this is already the case, given the class's name is "floatRight".... So no, this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this HTML out:

```
<div class="holder">   
    <span>blah</span>
    <input type="submit" name="button2" value="button2" class="floatRight" />
    <input type="submit" name="button1" value="button1" class="floatRight" />
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

And this css:

```
.clear{
    display: block;
    content: '';
    clear: both;
}
.floatRight{
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: It's alright, it solves the problem of offsetting my header element below the div, but they are still not inline. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Go trough your CSS and see if vertical-align is affected somewhere. You might check vertical-align and display.